# Routing with a Guid in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a url which will take the following form:

```
/AuditReview/Review/15d49a66-5c11-492c-921f-9e1700bd2618
```

I cannot get this to route, my routes look like this:

```
    MvcRoute.MappUrl("{controller}.mvc.aspx/{action}/{auditEventUid}")
        .WithDefaults(new {controller = "AuditReview", action = "Review"})
        .WithConstraints(new { controller = "AuditReview", action ="Review", auditEventUid = new GuidConstraint() });

    MvcRoute.MappUrl("admin/{controller}.mvc.aspx/{action}")
        .WithDefaults(new { controller = "audit", action = "index" })
        .WithConstraints(new{controller = "audit"})
        .AddWithName("admin", routes);

    MvcRoute.MappUrl("{controller}.mvc.aspx/{action}")
        .WithDefaults(new {action = "Index"})
        .AddWithName("Default", routes);
```

Can anyone suggest a route to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work - I am able to map a simpler scenario fine.  Can you get this scenario to work with a simpler route (e.g. the default "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}" route)?

Have you tried removing the GuidConstraint or testing to make sure that the GuidConstraint works?  Perhaps that is not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your current routing rules would require you to access the url using:

```
/AuditReview.mvc.aspx/Review/15d49a66-5c11-492c-921f-9e1700bd2618
```

If you're running IIS 7 or have enough access to the server to install [wildcard mapping](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx) you can just remove the `.mvc.aspx` from your routing rules and your original url will work.

Comment: The url I have posted is wrong, even with the .mvc.aspx extension it is still not routed

Comment: Do any of your other routes work (like the admin one?) or is it just this route?